# Proguard minifyEnabled true for debug build, not working on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

The methods count of my app is higher than the 64k limit, so I'm using Proguard to reduce it.

Everything works fine for release builds.
Debug builds, on the other hand, are successful only for Lollipop+ devices. When launching on pre-Lollipop devices I always have the infamous error:

`com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

This is what I have in the app level gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

I've tried removing `minifyEnabled true` in the debug build, and then the build fails also on Lollipop+, therefore proguard is working! but not on pre-Lollipop.

For what i know `minifyEnabled` should not be platform dependent, so maybe the build process skips it (for I don't know what reason) on pre-Lollipop devices.

Anyone knows a solution to this issue?

ps. I'm aware of the multidex possibility, but I'm leaving it as my last resort.

EDIT:

This is the full code of the app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.5'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pierfrancescosoffritti.shuffly"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 30
        versionName "0.13"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

def dbflow_version = "3.1.1"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    apt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidUtils:0.5'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:SlidingDrawer:0.10'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:WebBasedOAuth:0.7'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:ShrinkingImageLayout:0.4'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:ExpandableLayout:0.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev177-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.Commit451:ElasticDragDismissLayout:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

proguard rules:

```
# retrolambda
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

# picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# adMob
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}

# GoogleApiClient
# Needed to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**
# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**
# Needed by google-play-services when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
# com.google.client.util.IOUtils references java.nio.file.Files when on Java 7+
-dontnote java.nio.file.Files, java.nio.file.Path
# Suppress notes on LicensingServices
-dontnote **.ILicensingService
# Suppress warnings on sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

# DBFlow
-keep class * extends com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.DatabaseHolder { *; }
```

Comment: Don't you have dependencies that are only included for debug? Like, LeakCanary?

Comment: no, also I'm checking the methods count of the debug build with https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin and it's just fine. It's around 30k. (minifed with proguard)

Comment: please show full code of your gradle.build file

Comment: @Divers just added to the question

Comment: Please post also your root build.gradle file and proguard-rules.pro file

Comment: @Divers done, but I doubt the problem is there

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce this problem, probably because I was trying on almost empty project. I don't see why that problem could be here, only can suggest to try with latest build tools - `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`

Comment: Have you imported all the libraries?  It's really weird. It's like it uses another debug apk, just for pre lollipop devices.
buildTools 24.0.1 doesn't solve it.

Comment: btw I've tried with a new empty project and the problem is there :\

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try to reduce the method count, or at least you want to understand the difference from release to debug, I suggest you try looking at the dex count available in AS 2.2 preview 5, they had a youtube video (maybe from google IO) that made it pretty easy to count your methods.

This is only for counting methods, if you still use the same `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` you should get the exact same apk file in both versions of AS (apart from the fact that AS 2.2 ships with its own version of JDK, which is not supposed to get in your way).

Disclaimer: I have never used that tool apart from playing with it, so I wouldn't know what to recommend after you actually find a culprit there.

EDIT: here's the video https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?t=331 for the "Apk Analyzer", that lives inside the "Build" menu. Don't try reviews earlier than 2.2 preview 3 or later, they previewd some things that were not released until later.

EDIT 2: also why are you only using `shrinkResources` on release? That's the line that is suppposed to eliminate unneded methods: ["minifyEnabled" vs "shrinkResources" - what's the difference? and how to get the saved space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800804/minifyenabled-vs-shrinkresources-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-get-the)

Comment: I'm already counting my methods using https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin. The methods count is at 30k after being shrinked by proguard. So it's fine.

Comment: Hmm I'd try reading something about art then, wasn't that introduced in kit kat as optional and lollipop as stable? But still, do you have the same error in debug if you use the same info as release? Since these are default variants they may have hidden configuration apart from 'debuggable true'

Comment: Yep this is strange. I'd make sure to try and reproduce that problem by building and installing the apk without AS, or at least if you're doing with it make sure to turn off instant run. And also I'd double check the method count for your debug build with a second script/gradle plugin just to make sure, because that error message is very particular to hitting the 65k method count.

Comment: I was in the same case and adding `shrinkResources true` on debug block did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your build Types code with this code in app level gradle file.
when you are debugging or running code on your device before final release then select built variant debug and when you are going to built signed apk for release then select built variant release

```
  buildTypes {
                debug {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
                release {
                    shrinkResources true
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Enable multidex enabled true and allow support to your application as a multidex application.Few steps to be followed are:

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.1"
        **multiDexEnabled true**
    }
```

add this dependency to dependency list

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

extend your application level class with MultiDexApplication

write this method in your application class

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

keep minifyEnabled false no matter debug or release build

update

```
dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
```

Comment: as I said: "ps. I'm aware of the multidex possibility, but I'm leaving it as my last resort."