# Android button ImageButton not displaying image when run in release mode

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to use an `ImageButton` to display a resource, a `.png` as a clickable button. When I run my app in debug, the `ImageButton` sources the image correctly.

[image]

However, when I run the app in release mode the `ImageButton` doesn't display the drawable:

[image]

I create and populate my `ImageButton`s programmatically with:

```
    private void setupButtons() {

        FlexboxLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.telcosLayout);
        final Activity activity = getActivity(); 

        // Telcom is an enum
        for (final Telcom t : Telcom.values()) {
            ImageButton b = new ImageButton(activity);

            int id = getId(t.toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") + "_logo", R.drawable.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "id is " + id);
            b.setImageResource(id);

            layout.addView(b);

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scanButtonListener.onShowScanButton(t);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

And the output of my logs when run in release mode is:

```
2019-10-13 11:07:49.500 25757-25757/? I/select telcome: id is 2131165284
2019-10-13 11:07:49.501 25757-25757/? I/select telcome: id is 2131165320
```

And here are the logs from running the app in debug mode:

```
2019-10-13 11:12:22.575 26146-26146/com.glan.input I/select telcome: id is 2131165284
2019-10-13 11:12:22.583 26146-26146/com.glan.input I/select telcome: id is 2131165320
```

It seems the same drawables are being found in both modes but for some reason they won't display in release mode. What is going on?

I've verified that the drawable exists for all the screen densities from `drawable-ldpi` to `drawable-xxxhdpi`.

I've also found that if I hardcode `b.setImageResource(2131165284);` based on the log lines, the `ImageButton` displays the same image for both buttons in both debug and release mode, which is expected behavior.

[image]

How come dynamically setting the resource doesn't work in release mode?

EDIT: Ok, I think I found the problem. My release build mode has the following properties:

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
```

When I disabled `shrinkResources`, by commenting it out, the images appeared again. It seems that, based on ["minifyEnabled" vs "shrinkResources" - what's the difference? and how to get the saved space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800804/minifyenabled-vs-shrinkresources-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-get-the), ProGuard detects that the resources I depend, the `.png` drawables, on aren't used because they're dynamically requested and so `shrinkResources` removes them entirely.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. The solution that worked for me was to use `tools:keep` from https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolskeep to purposefully keep those resources even with `shrinkResources` set to `true`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703322/1489726

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if its happening because the image is taking up too many resources? How large is the image file? Is it the same dimension as the button?

Android will not allow the app in release mode to take so many resources. I'd suggest you use a library like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) for setting the image resource on the ImageButton. Picasso will handle the resizing of the resource for the screen and button size itself.

And it's very easy to use as well.

Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.your_image_resource).into(yourImageButton);

https://square.github.io/picasso/