# cloud_firestore/unavailable The service is currently unavailable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore in my flutter application. Everything works fine in `debug` mode. But, in `release` mode I get the following error.
I saw a similar question, but it doesn't solve my issue.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] 
The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.
E/flutter ( 3646): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get 
(package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:80)
E/flutter ( 3646): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3646): #1      DocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:58)
E/flutter ( 3646): <asynchronous suspension>
```

```
$ flutter doctor
>> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, Version 10.0.21996.1)
>> • No issues found!
```

I tried

- Adding `INTERNET` permission.
- Changing Gradle Versions.
- Changing Firebase package versions

Current Versions

```
firebase_core: 1.6.0
firebase_auth: 2.0.0
cloud_firestore: 1.0.7
```

Any help/suggestions would be so grateful.

Comment: I have the same issue , have you found any solution for this !

Comment: I upgraded the packages to the latest versions. Now it works for me.

Answer (score 9):

Build using

```
flutter build --no-shrink
```

or go to `Android > app > build.gradle` and
add

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        
    }
}
```

Comment: this was the real fix for me

Comment: Why does this work? Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @Loolooii code shrinking is a part of optimization process, shrinking removes unused code in release mode. I don't know exactly why it removes firebase package, but it does that. That's why we configure it for 'no-shrink'. You can read about it from here [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) and [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android) and see the section that mentions Code shrinking with R8

Comment: @IshfaqKhawaja minifyEnabled is by default false, and is minifyEnabled is false shrinkResources would be ignored. So how is it fixing the issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800804/minifyenabled-vs-shrinkresources-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-get-the

Comment: @SaurabhKumar try cleaning your flutter app, then build using this
     *flutter build --no-shrink*

Comment: @IshfaqKhawaja pls read my comment again in case no clear flutter build --no-shrink will not do anything since `shrinkResources` is by default False.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Firebase core and Firestore to the latest version solved the issue for me.

Comment: I'm on latest version and this still happening

Answer (score 0):

I think `it is not an issue of library`. `It is coding issue`, please check some below ways to fix it:

- Option 1: Upgrading cloud_firestore and firebase core to latest version, then running command `flutter clean` and `flutter run`.
- Option 2: Firebase profile issue.

1. Checking Firebase profile in `production mode` or `test mode`?. Try to switch it for testing.
2. Checking collection is exist. ie `users` is exist on `firestore`?

- Option 3: The logged-in user didn't exist on the auth emulator and Firestore kept refusing to return the data to the unauthorized user. So please log out and created a new user account.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to check exist

```dart
final doc = await docRef.doc(docId).get();
// got error here
data = doc.data();
```

fixed by add check exits

```html
final doc = await docRef.doc(docId).get();
if (doc.exists) {
    data = doc.data();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking, there is a recent issue with a package dependency incompatibility for cloud_firestore and mlkit you may experience.

See the official issue here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5197

You will know if this is your issue by looking at the logs, if you find the following error message that is likely it:

```
W/Firestore( 7928): (24.7.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuffer()Lokio/Buffer; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource'
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I had to enable Cloud Firestore API (via a sample URL below) to get the job done. Make sure the database exists for the cited project in the firebase.  Sometimes times internet affected it as well.

Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project whatsapp-439af before or it is disabled.
Enable it by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=abcdef-1234f
then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was solved by creating a database in firestore. Try creating a database in firestore using [this](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/data?_gl=1*nu8lvb*_ga*MTY0NDgyMjYyNC4xNzAxOTIxNTc4*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcwNzExMzMwNC4yNC4xLjE3MDcxMTQxNDUuNjAuMC4w) link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching between firebase emulator and live firebase then uninstall the app and restarting the device fixes this issue.